# How to change background immediately?

Tags: java, javafx

In the code below the pane's background color would change **only AFTER** input, not before. And I can't understand why: as far as I know, program should start waiting for input only after the line `sc.next();`. Is there any way to force background changing? To perform it before waiting for input?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.println(str);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely (since `sc.next()` is a *blocking call*)  you are blocking the *Event Dispatch Thread*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Actually the *FX Application Thread*. The Event Dispatch Thread is the name of the thread used by AWT and Swing for rendering those UIs and processing events on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `sc.next()` will block until the user provides input. Since the `start()` method is executed on the FX Application Thread, which is the thread that is used to render the UI, the rendering of the UI can't happen until this block is released.

It's really not clear why you would read from standard input in a GUI application anyway; the whole point of a GUI application is that you provide controls (text fields, buttons, etc) for the user to provide input.

If you really wanted to read from standard input for some reason, you would need to do so in a background thread:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();

    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        System.out.println(str);
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Note that you cannot update the UI from the background thread, so if you wanted to use the input in the UI, you would need further code to make the UI changes happen on the FX Application Thread.